# xmlsignature of Android manifest?

Tags: android, signature

is there any way how to implement xml signature into android manifest? When I download APK file all I need is to verify its signature and if its ok, then prompt installation, otherwise display error message. Is is possible for Android?

Thanks

Comment: The APK files are usually signed. Probably you should be searching for APK signature verification code.

Comment: The OS verifies the signature of the app at install time automatically. Why do you need to do it too? Are you trying to say you want your application to verify the signature of a second downloaded application at run-time?

Comment: Can you tell me if you found the solution ?